# send parameters from drop_receiving_element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototype

users can be dragged to nodes to move or copy a user from one node to another node. I have a problem with how I send the variables to user move and copy methods in userscontrol.

The drop zone is defined as:

```
<%=drop_receiving_element "move_drop_zone_"+node.id.to_s, 
  :update => "users", 
  :url => move_user_path(:id => node.id),
  :method => :put,
  :accept => "move_user" %>
```

The draggable user in a node is defined as:

```
<span id="move_user_<%=user.id%>_<%= node.id.to_s %>" class="move_user" >
  <%=image_tag('move_user.png') %>
</span> 
<%= draggable_element "move_user_" + user_node, :revert => true %>
```

I also added to routes:

```
map.resources :users, :member => { :move => :put, :copy => :put }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the user id and from node id. Since it's a put operation I only see the id (which is the target node id) defined in the url of drop_receiving_element.

Thanks,
Stijn

Comment: You can't just keep posting the same question with slightly different wording!

Comment: keep posting the same question? stackoverflow.com/questions/950093/… is about routing. I don't feel the questions are related and thus should be seperated, no?

Comment: I would say that both questions are about the problem of passing the user ID and node ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you could use the `:with` parameter of `drop_receiving_element`?

[drop_receiving_element Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/ScriptaculousHelper.html#M001610)

Comment: :with - A JavaScript expression specifying the parameters for the XMLHttpRequest. Any expressions should return a valid URL query string.

If I understand it correctly :with just passes extra parameters? The problem is that I don't see how I can know the user_id and the from_node_id since they are part of the draggable_element and not the receiving_element.